# How to retrieve both user info and big image

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-fql, inner-join

For an Android app, I'm trying to get some info of a specific user (using its user id) on Facebook using FQL, and also get a high quality image of the user.

This means I have to use both the "user" table and the "photo" table.

Currently, the queries are:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, status, current_location, uid, pic_square, pic_big, website, work, email, contact_email, current_location, sex, birthday_date 
FROM user 
WHERE uid in (%s) order by name

SELECT src_big,owner 
FROM photo 
WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=%s AND type=\"profile\") LIMIT 1
```

The first one returns all of the info of the specified users, and the second one returns the `src_big` of a single user. Is it possible to do inner join and do them both in a single query?

EDIT:

It seems that inner join is still impossible for FQL. However, I still wish to ask something about this: how do I change the second FQL statement to show multiple results, as used in the first FQL statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, an FQL multiquery doesn't give you the ability to select one item per user in the result. Your second query will give you just one item. You would need to get all photos from all users in FQL and then filter them in your app, or make a separate API call per user.

You can do this with the Graph API using [field expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/). Your query endpoint will be:

```
 /?ids=UID_1,UID_2,...,UID_n&fields=name,id,...,photo.limit(1)
```

Since you're using the `fields` parameter, you will need to individually declare each field you want in your result.

Comment: sadly i had to hurry and use a working solution so i've implemented it so that i store the results and do the joining myself . however , according to what i see here , you won't have all of the fields of the users in one query result. one will have the info , and one will have the src_big and the owner . i want both of the together , which is why i wanted to do inner join. did you mean that this will solve the fact that the second statement only returns a single result ?

Comment: Yes, I see where your problem is. No FQL isn't the tool for the job here. Edit coming.

Comment: yes i understand . can i at least somehow change the second query so that it returns multiple results instead of a single one ? i will use the results from the first query , of course...

Comment: The problem is you can't limit the results to one photo per user as you want in FQL. You can get what you want using the Graph API. See here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=%3Fids%3Dme%26fields%3Did%2Cfirst_name%2Clast_name%2Clocation%2Cpicture%2Cstatuses.limit(1)%2Cphotos.limit(1)

Comment: If you wanted an FQL solution, you would need to make a separate query per `uid`. Not bad if you have 5 uids, but if you've got 50 it's not manageable.

Comment: that's what i did - i made a query for each uid , but this is not a good thing (as you've written) , so my question is how i can make it better using FQL .

Comment: You can't with FQL. Use the Graph API code above (example link in my last comment). That gets you exactly what you want.

Comment: even that i can't? can't believe how uncomfortable working with facebook is . wonder if it's the same on IOS . anyway , thanks.

Comment: can you please tell me which table/tables in the GraphApi should i look at?

Comment: There is an example query in my answer and a working example if you follow the developers.facebook.com link in my comment above. You need to look at both the `user` and `photos` tables in the API, but with field expansion, you can connect them.

Comment: thank you again . the example you've shown doesn't work , or maybe i miss there something . anyway , i thank you for your answers.

Comment: Hmm. The SO parser doesn't like parens in URLs. Here is a bitly link that does work: http://bit.ly/RyM9dX

Answer (score -2):

Of course you can, join two tables, use user.uid = photo.owner(if correct) as the binding condition.

Comment: i don't understand , what is the query i should use , and what is "if correct" ?